# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.sql.SQLType" on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

When I try to connect a MySQL database directly with JDBC on Android, I got the Exception like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.sql.SQLType" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar",...
```

and my test code is here:

```
package com.kurosei.app.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER,PWD);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and my **build.gradle** is here:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kurosei.app.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.11'

}
```

- The version of JDK is 1.8.0_152
- The version of Gradle Plugin is 3.1.3
- The version of Android Studio is 3.1.2

Don't ask why I choose this way to access the database...

Comment: That interface was introduced in Java 8, Android doesn't support Java 8 (or at least doesn't include the `java.sql.SQLType` interface introduced in Java 8), and you you shouldn't even be connecting directly to a MySQL database from an android device. It is insecure, and likely to perform very badly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an existing app on the Play Store called RemoDB to connect to your database. If you still prefer to connect yourself, you can try using the versions 6.x.x of the jdbc driver

Answer (score 0):

You may want to include JBoss JDBC Wrapper, added below in gradle

```
implementation files('libs/jboss-common-jdbc-wrapper.jar')
```